# How to find an alphanumeric String where String.hashcode yields an integer value?

Tags: java

I have a set of integer values. I am looking to find as many alphanumeric Strings as I can that hashes to each of my values.Could anyone give me advice on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Could you include a sample of what you are trying to do, possibly some code you have attempted?

Comment: would you like to have a reverse-engineering of hashcode function?